# Adding multiple source files to build in Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, build

I'm developing a code which uses [Easylogging++](https://muflihun.github.io/easyloggingpp/) as the underlying logging library. Recently, I wanted to update the library since it has some high visibility / high impact bugs and I found out that the library is divided into two files (`.cc` and `.h`). This new structure needs inclusion of the `.cc` file in the build string alongside the main program code.

I'm using Eclipse to develop the project and generate the make files to build the project. I need to tell Eclipse (Oxygen.1) that it needs to compile the `.cc` file alongside the main file while building the project, however I was unable to do so. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does this have to do with the Autotools?

Comment: Eclipse uses autotools to generate its makefiles automatically at the background IIRC (If that's a wrong tag, I can happily remove it). In other words, I'm trying to make Eclipse to include a `.cc` file in the root compilation command.

Comment: Eclipse *can* use the Autotools, but it only does so for projects that you configure that way.  I genuinely like the Autotools, but the only reason to configure an Eclipse project that way is if you import a project into Eclipse that has an existing Autotools-based build system.

Comment: I started the project as a *Makefile project* years ago. Eclipse is managing and generating the makefiles. Since I'm developing the code for some years, I never had to fiddle with that part until the library's developer fiddled with his code. I *guessed* it was using autotools at the back, but I'm not very knowledgeable at that area honestly.

Comment: A "makefile project" is expressly *not* an Autotools project.  Eclipse CDT handles building your makefiles directly in a makefile project.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easier than I thought. Eclipse's managed build is more intelligent than it seems. Adding many source files under the `/src` folder causes Eclipse to automatically compile all the files under that folder, unless you exclude them.

This means adding the `.h` to `/lib` folder and the `.cc` file to the `/src` folder and modifying to `.cc` to look for the `.h` file under `/lib` have solved the problem neatly.

To complete the compilation I had to add some flags, since the developer likes to extensively modify his library between releases.

Everything is working fine again.

Comment: I have it built successfully just like you.   However, did you find out how to get it to built within a single step?  I posted my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52380156/how-to-build-from-multiple-source-files-at-once-in-eclipse).  TIA!

Comment: When you add all the necessary source files, if the whole source tree has a single `main ()` call, it already builds on single step. If you have more than one `main ()` function, you need to create build profiles to build all binaries independently.