# How to build from multiple source files at once in Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, compilation, g++

I have an Eclipse C++ project which initially has `first.cpp`.  Then `second.cpp` is added and should be linked to the original file.  Using Eclipse building tool, I got this output:

```
make all 
Building file: ../src/first.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -I/home/workspace/first/src -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/first.d" -MT"src/first.o" -o "src/first.o" "../src/first.cpp"
Finished building: ../src/first.cpp
 
Building file: ../src/second.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -I/home/workspace/first/src -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/second.d" -MT"src/second.o" -o "src/second.o" "../src/second.cpp"
Finished building: ../src/second.cpp
 
Building target: first
Invoking: GCC C++ Linker
g++ -L/usr/local/lib -o "first"  ./src/first.o ./src/second.o
Finished building target: first
```

How can I get Eclipse to compile this way?

```
g++ first.cpp second.cpp -o first
```

### Update

I am asking how to make a single binary from multiple source files, not [building multiple binaries with multiple source files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2424795/building-multiple-binaries-within-one-eclipse-project).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Building multiple binaries within one Eclipse project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2424795/building-multiple-binaries-within-one-eclipse-project)

Comment: No, that's not it!  You didn't read my question carefully.  That answer is to produce multiple binaries.  I want to make a single binary from multiple source files.

Comment: [This might provide you what you are looking for.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/513697/6390175)
or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26830341/6390175) *let me know if it resolves your issue.*

Comment: All the source files are found under the `src` folder as seen in the build output above.  They build fine, but the process is incremental and they all get linked together in the final step.  I am looking to for a way to build them all in a single command, as per question.

Comment: Have you considered using cmake ??

Comment: Never had any experience, but I will be glad to get some pointers for my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [CMake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMake)
As per my understanding of your question, you would need to add your source files into *`CMakeList.txt`* and then run it. You can make use of [this tutorial](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/quick-cmake-tutorial.html) in doing so.

Comment: Well, well, well.  The journey ends with another adventure into `c/make`, something I thought I could avoid.

Comment: Well, it's always exciting to learn something new. I am sure you'll appreciate it once you will start practicing it. :) Happy learning

Comment: And you can accept the answer so others may find it useful as well :)

Comment: @J.Doe It doesn't and I can't do anything about it.